# getting file icon(bitmap) while file dragging and dropping in c++

Tags: c++, win32gui

When I am dragging and dropping a single file from my application to Explorer, the single file's image is appearing.  But I want to drag multiple files and have multiple file images appear. Can anyone help with this please?

[Dragging a shell object, part 4: Adding a prettier drag icon](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=37083)

```
HRESULT GetDataObjectOfFileWithCuteIcon(HWND hwnd,LPCWSTR pszPath, IDataObject** ppdto)
{
    HRESULT hr; /*= GetUIObjectOfFile(hwnd, pszPath,

        IID_IDataObject, (void**)ppdto);*/

    //if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    {

        IDragSourceHelper* pdsh;

        if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DragDropHelper, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IDragSourceHelper, (void**)& pdsh))) {
            HIMAGELIST himl;
            SHDRAGIMAGE sdi;
            SIZE sz;
            ZeroMemory(&sdi, sizeof(SHDRAGIMAGE));

            sdi.crColorKey = CLR_NONE;
            SHFILEINFOW sfi = { };
            int UFlag = SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON;
            UFlag  ^= SHGFI_SMALLICON;
            //himl  = (HIMAGELIST)              SHGetFileInfoW(L"C:\\Users\\Venkatesh\\Desktop", 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), UFlag| SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
            himl  = (HIMAGELIST)                SHGetFileInfoW(L"C:\\Users\\Venkatesh\\Desktop\\TestPage.pdf", 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), UFlag| SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
            if (himl)
            {
                int cx, cy;              

                ImageList_GetIconSize(himl, &cx, &cy);

                sdi.sizeDragImage.cx = cx;

                sdi.sizeDragImage.cy = cy;
                sdi.ptOffset.x = cx;

                sdi.ptOffset.y = cy;

                sdi.crColorKey = CLR_NONE;

                sdi.hbmpDragImage = CreateBitmap(cx, cy, 1, 32, NULL);
                HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
                if (sdi.hbmpDragImage) {
                //  GetObject(sdi.hbmpDragImage, sizeof(BITMAP), &sdi.hbmpDragImage);
                    HBITMAP hbmPrev = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc, (HGDIOBJ)sdi.hbmpDragImage);
                    ImageList_Draw(himl, sfi.iIcon, hdc, 0, 0, ILD_SCALE);
                //  ImageList_Draw(himl, sfi.iIcon, hdc, 0, 0, ILD_TRANSPARENT);
                    SelectObject(hdc, hbmPrev);
                    //if (CreateDragImage(pszPath, &sdi)) {

                    pdsh->InitializeFromBitmap(&sdi, *ppdto);
                    DeleteDC(hdc);


                    DeleteObject(sdi.hbmpDragImage);
                }
                //}


            }
        }
        pdsh->Release();
    }
    hr = S_OK;
    return hr;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't provide multiple images. You will have to retrieve each file's image and merge them together into a single bitmap as desired (for instance, when dragging image files from Explorer, it renders thumbnails of the files on top of each other in a stacked appearance), and then you can give that final bitmap to `IDragSourceHelper`

Comment: I am trying to create all bitmaps of dragged files using SHGetFileInfoW API this is taking only one file path   i dont know how to pass all file paths and  capture all file images please provide some APIs so that i can  retrieve each file's image so that i can merge them

Comment: you have to load the file bitmaps *individually*, you can't load them all at one time. Create a *new* bitmap and draw the individual file bitmaps onto it as needed, then use that new bitmap as the drag image

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau Hi Thank you for your reply i am able to take multiple images but dont know  how to merge them could you please help  me how to merge them .provide with some code or APIs you help will be appreciated

Comment: do you know how to create a new bitmap? Do you know how to draw on a bitmap? If not, go research those topics first. Look at [Bitmap Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/bitmap-creation), [Bitmaps, Device Contexts, and Drawing Surfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/bitmaps--device-contexts--and-drawing-surfaces), [Memory Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/memory-device-contexts), and [`BitBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt).